# Could CSS be used in Survey?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, survey

Could CSS elements or attributes contribute to survey of a particular action such as a `profile change`?

Recently, I was surprised that facebook had this Internet.org where it went for a controller CSS entity change for for this they did the same with Gay Rights initiative as mentioned below:

[image]

Could it lead to activation of any survey like counting how many profiles were changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". According to my experience, using css class names can be used to select data from DOM using javascript or other client side scripting mechanisms. So there is a possibility that FB may be using some kind of analytics/survey type system, that actually inspects the profile/friendlist/group/commentslist or whatever to check if the profile pic element also have the "internetorg" class attached to it.

But still, it is not making any sense why FB should use some kind of client side stuff when they have one of the world's best h/w infra for these type of applications.

Comment: appears that desperate time, desperate measures. FB is down to fix issues while I type this.